# Keyboard input passed by SendInput() (Win32 API) dont work on some computers

Tags: c++, winapi

Sorry for stupid question, but solving this three days and no progress was seen.

I have a library which sending via Win32 API messages about mouse clicks and sequence of keyboard strokes passed by SendInput.

All works ok on my computer (and newly installed W7 as virtual machine too), but on some computers (my client's and wife's one) is totally ignored SendInput and sequence of keystrokes is not sent.

Here is part of relevant code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall PutKeystroke(int times, BOOL isDown)
{
    INPUT ip = {0};
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wVk =isDown? VK_DOWN : VK_UP;

    //std::vector<INPUT> ips;
    //ips.reserve((times*2)+2);
    INPUT ips[100] = {0};

    for(int i = 0; i < times*2; i+=2)
    {
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
        ips[i] = ip;
        //ips.push_back(ip);

        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        //ips.push_back(ip);
        ips[i+1] = ip;
    }

    ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;
    ip.ki.wVk = VK_RETURN;
    ips[times*2] = ip;
    //ips.push_back(ip);

    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    ips[(times*2)+1] = ip;
    //ips.push_back(ip);

    SendInput((times*2)+2, &ips[0], sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

(Commented lines is C++ variant, but both variants behaves equally - on my machines works well, but on others not)

Is here anyone who had similar problem and know solution what need to  be done?

Of course, I tried run the program as admin, but nothing different.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can't you use automation instead of faking input?

Comment: You are probably looking for [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There probably was an application window, that receiving keystrokes beyond a another window, no matters which, but controls was not fully visible. 
Helps with bring target widnow to foregroud, using ShowWindow applied to parent window handle like this:

```
ShowWindow(GetParent(clickSettings.GetHandler), SW_SHOW);
```

and then send needed keystrokes.